# The relation between the Black-Scholes model and quantum mechanics

Tags: black-scholes-model, interdisciplinary, mathematical-economics

As an active participant on the Physics Stack Exchange I have, on several separate occasions, run into some vague remarks about the 'intimate relation' between the famous Black-Scholes model in economics and the Schrödinger equation that appears in quantum mechanics. In particular, people mention that *path integrals* (a certain technique that is very useful in quantum mechanical calculations) find many applications in economic settings.

I'd love if someone could make this connection clearer by

- Explicitly (i.e. in equations) showing how the Schrödinger equation and the Black-Scholes equation are related
- Discussing the use of path integrals in economics

Comment: P.S. Please feel free to add (or remove) tags; I'm not an expert in economics.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit for [Quantitative Finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @SteveS would this not fall in the category *economics*? Curious...

Comment: Well, to the extent that Quantitative Finance is a subset of Economics, sure. (Frankly, I've always wondered why "Quantitative Finance" came before "Economics" anyway). It's just that my initial impulse was that, well, it'd fit in better over at a more-narrowly focused site like the Quant StackExchange.

Comment: I agree with Steve. The Black-Scholes is very related to quantitative financing, which is only one small portion of economics as a whole.

Comment: @NateVomocil I'm still not sure that this should make it *off-topic* here. Could someone provide a reference to better understand what this SE *is* intended for?

Comment: @Danu: It's not that it's off-topic, per se--just that I think it's **more on-topic** over at Quant SE (if that makes sense).

Comment: @SteveS I wonder if we might benefit from a meta discussion as to whether we should avoid poaching questions that can go on specific sub-discipline stacks? :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because pertains much more to quantitative finance than economics.

Comment: @daOnlyBG that doesn't make it off-topic. It's a valid economics question. The fact that it could be on-topic at another site doesn't make it off-topic here at all. Whether it's answerable, and whether it's an appropriate expert question, is a different matter: but just being valid on more than one SE site is not a sufficient reason to close or to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

I have more often heard of how the Black-Scholes equation is just the heat equation. You can find that information [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/84/transformation-from-the-black-scholes-differential-equation-to-the-diffusion-equ). I haven't heard of a relationship between Black-Scholes and quantum mechanics before, but [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60242/relation-between-black-scholes-equation-and-quantum-mechanics) post on the Physics stack exchange seems to have the details you're looking for. (Maybe you've seen this post before.)

Comment: Yes, the Black-Scholes differential equation can be transformed into the heat equation by a change of variables.

Comment: Well, the Schrodinger equation is the complex analysis equivalent of the heat equation so the relationship seems legit.